# Setting value of dropdown box to last submitted value with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the following dropdown box

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" ACTION="songs.php">
Select Category: <select id="sel" name="categories" onchange="document.myform.submit()">
```

And all the options follow after. When the user makes a selection, the category is brought up below using PHP and MYSQl based on the selection containing a list of songs etc.

However, the dropdown box always defaults back to the first value in the list of options. How do I make so that the dropdown box will set the selected option to the last submitted value? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with JS as it has no direct access to POST request parameters. Rather let the server side language (which is in your case PHP) print the `selected` attribute on the `<option>` element whenever the submitted value matches the option value.

E.g.

```
foreach ($options as $value => $label) {
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . ($selected == $value ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $label . '</option>';
}
```